# Where can I find free shapefiles of oil/natural gas pipelines in Mexico?

Tags: data, oil-gas, mexico, pipe-network

I'm looking for free shapefiles of oil or natural gas pipelines pertaining specifically to Mexico or even trans-national pipelines between the U.S and Mexico.

Comment: This sort of information is generally restricted (for anti-terrorism/public safety reasons).  The odds of getting free accurate data are not large.

Comment: There are one or two maps via Google images that you could georefrence and digitize as a starting point. As Vince mentions it will be difficult to get free data unless you can contact a vendor such as IHS with a view of buying a specific dataset. The problem being is that they may charge a lot.